# Jade 'each' iterator is iterating extra object properties?

Tags: javascript, express, pug

I'm using node, express, and jade. I seem to be iterating over two extra object properties added by jade. I'm passing in rows which is an array of objects.

**app**

```
conn.query( 'SELECT * FROM invoice ORDER BY account ASC',
            function (err, rows, fields) {
              console.log(rows);
              res.render('index', { rows: rows, fields: fields  })
});
```

**index.jade:**

```
table(border=1)
  each row in rows
    tr
      each cell in row
        td= cell
```

**console.log**

```
[ { id: 34,
    account: 'abcdefg' } ]
```

**http://localhost/** this is one of the extra properties that i get when iterating through the objects.

```
<td>function (field, parser, timeZone) {
  switch (field.type) {
    case Types.TIMESTAMP:
    case Types.DATE:
    case Types.DATETIME:
    case Types.NEWDATE:
      var dateString = parser.parseLengthCodedString();
      if (dateString === null) {
        return null;
  }

  if (timeZone != 'local') {
    if (field.type === Types.DATE) {
      dateString += ' 00:00:00 ' + timeZone;
    } else {
      dateString += timeZone;
    }
  }

  return new Date(dateString);
case Types.TINY:
case Types.SHORT:
case Types.LONG:
case Types.INT24:
case Types.YEAR:
case Types.FLOAT:
case Types.DOUBLE:
case Types.LONGLONG:
case Types.NEWDECIMAL:
  var numberString = parser.parseLengthCodedString();
  return (numberString === null || (field.zeroFill &amp;&amp; numberString[0] == &quot;0&quot;))
    ? numberString
    : Number(numberString);
case Types.BIT:
  return parser.parseLengthCodedBuffer();
case Types.STRING:
case Types.VAR_STRING:
case Types.TINY_BLOB:
case Types.MEDIUM_BLOB:
case Types.LONG_BLOB:
case Types.BLOB:
  return (field.charsetNr === Charsets.BINARY)
    ? parser.parseLengthCodedBuffer()
    : parser.parseLengthCodedString();
case Types.GEOMETRY:
  return parser.parseGeometryValue();
default:
  return parser.parseLengthCodedString();
  }
}</td>
```

Comment: What does `Object.keys(cell)` return? Or use the `each val, key in obj` form and see what the name of the property is. I'm guessing this is some function tacked on to your returned objects by your DB library.

Comment: I thought it might have been extra properties from the database as well, i did a console.log(rows) (which i forgot to include in the app example, i will update the info above) just immediately before the res.render() call and it output the console.log section above with no extra properties.